FLUTTER NotifyListeners throws exception
I just moved to a new computer but just after I installed flutter and VS Code and etc I am trying to debug my code but it gives this error on all of notifyListeners.
The same code works and debugs fine on my old computer.
I am debugging on the Android Samsung phone.


Exception has occurred. FlutterError (setState() or markNeedsBuild()
called during build. This _InheritedProviderScope<LoginListViewModel?>
widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is
already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as
needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its
ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the
framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty
descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not
visit this widget during this build phase. The widget on which
setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
_InheritedProviderScope<LoginListViewModel?> The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was: Builder)

The results of Flutter Doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.12, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3447], locale tr-TR)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2023.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.90.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Here is the pubspec.yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  sizer: ^2.0.15
  http: ^0.13.5
  provider: ^6.0.5
  intl: ^0.18.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.17
  badges: ^3.0.2
  flutter_beep: ^1.0.0
  qr_code_scanner: ^1.0.1
  grouped_list: ^5.1.2
  pdf: ^3.10.1
  path_provider: ^2.1.1
  printing: ^5.10.4
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.19
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  open_document: ^1.0.7
  google_fonts: ^4.0.4
  change_app_package_name: ^1.1.0
  flutter_email_sender: ^6.0.1
  simple_vcard_parser: ^0.2.0
  dropdown_search: ^5.0.6

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  

The same code debugs fine in the old computer while gives this error on the newer one.
I tried to make the Flutter SDK same in both computers and all the versions.
